# Vuetify Navigation Drawer doesn't show with Vuex

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vuetify.js

I am trying to get a Vuetify navigation drawer to open up on click of a hamburger menu. So far I've got an app component with two child components, `<navbar/>` and `<drawer/>`.

```
<template>
   <v-app>
     <navbar/>
     <drawer v-show='showSideBar'/>
     <router-view></router-view>
   </v-app>
</template>

<script>
  import { mapState, mapActions, mapGetters } from 'vuex';
  import Navbar from '@/_components/Navbar/Navbar';
  import Drawer from '@/_components/Drawer/Drawer';

  export default {
    name: "app",
    computed: {  
      ...mapGetters('navbar', {
        showSideBar: 'g_sideBarOpen',
      })
    },
    components: {
      Navbar,
      Drawer,
    }
  };
</script>
```

Navbar.vue:

```
<template>
    ...
    <v-toolbar-side-icon 
      :ripple='false'
      @click.stop='toggleSideBar'
    ></v-toolbar-side-icon>
</template>

<script>
  import { mapState, mapActions } from 'vuex';

  export default {
    data: () => ({
      items: [
        { 
          title: 'Profile',
          url  : '/profile',
        },
        { 
          title: 'Logout',
          url  : '/login',
        },
      ],
    }),
    components: {
      Logo,
    },
    computed: {
      ...mapState({
        account: state => state.account,
      }),  
    },
    methods: {
      ...mapActions('navbar', [
        'toggleSideBar',
      ]),
    }
  }
</script>
```

Drawer.vue:

```
<template>
  <v-navigation-drawer absolute temporary>
    <v-list class="pa-1">
      <v-list-tile avatar>
        <v-list-tile-avatar>
          <img src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/85.jpg">
        </v-list-tile-avatar>

        <v-list-tile-content>
          <v-list-tile-title>John Leider</v-list-tile-title>
        </v-list-tile-content>
      </v-list-tile>
    </v-list>

    <v-list class="pt-0" dense>
      <v-divider></v-divider>

      <v-list-tile v-for="item in items" :key="item.title">
        <v-list-tile-action>
          <v-icon>{{ item.icon }}</v-icon>
        </v-list-tile-action>

        <v-list-tile-content>
          <v-list-tile-title>{{ item.title }}</v-list-tile-title>
        </v-list-tile-content>
      </v-list-tile>
    </v-list>
  </v-navigation-drawer>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data: () => ({
      items: [
        {
          title: "Profile",
          url: "/profile"
        },
        {
          title: "Logout",
          url: "/login"
        }
      ]
    })
  };
</script>
```

My `navbar.module.js` is as follows:

```
const state = {
  sideBarOpen: false,
};

const getters = {
  g_sideBarOpen(state) {
    return state.sideBarOpen
  }
};

const actions = {
  toggleSideBar({ commit }) {
    commit('toggleSideBar');
  },
};

const mutations = {
  toggleSideBar(state) {
    state.sideBarOpen = !state.sideBarOpen;
  }
};

export const navbar = {
  namespaced: true,
  state,
  actions,
  getters,
  mutations,
};
```

Looking at the Vue/Vuex devtools, I can tell that the Vuex portion of things is working correctly and state correctly updates to reflect that `sideBarOpen` is either false or true.

When I click the hamburger and verify that sideBarOpen is true, and inspect the DOM, it appears to me that the `transform: translateX(-300px)` style doesn't change at all, and in fact when I remove that property I can see the drawer move correctly into view.

[image: vuetify drawer]

I can't figure out for the life of me what the issue is, but I feel like it's something simple. Has anybody run into a similar issue?

*Edited to include Navbar.vue

Comment: I'm not too familiar with vuetify.js, but i don't see how `v-show` affects the `transform` css property of the drawer component. `v-show` simply changes whether or not a component is displayed (using the css `display` property) and is a directive available to all components. Are you sure you are using the correct prop for `drawer`?

Comment: Great point, I think I saw that on a tutorial somewhere. The Vuetify examples show it with `v-model=""` and their navigation-drawer api shows the prop "value" as what controls visibility. I've definitely tried both of those routes though and none seem to appear for me for whatever reason.

Comment: Well...what does your `Drawer` component look like? Vuetify only seems to have `v-navigation-drawer`

Comment: I've updated my post with Drawer.vue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `v-model='showSideBar'` instead of 'v-show'. The prop `value` is actually tied to the `v-model` directive. `v-show` would work if your drawer wasn't `temporary`, but `temporary` drawers will have its `transform` CSS value set to your negative value to 'hide' it from view until you display the drawer by setting its `value` prop to `true`.

Play around with [this](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gyRgZG?&editable=true&editors=101) and change the `temporary` directive with `permanent`, `v-show` with `v-model` and the `thing` data variable.

Note, you need to set `v-model` within `v-navigation-drawer`, not `drawer`. It's up to you how you pass the value of `showSideBar`, but just note that the `Drawer` component itself isn't using `v-model` in any way but `v-navigation-drawer` is.

Comment: Ah there we go! I pasted the Drawer html into the App.vue to test it and added `v-model='showSideBar'` and it's appeared to work! I'll need to just figure out how to then pass it on to the Drawer component, but that's outside the scope of this question. Thanks for all of your help!